# Perl BEGIN failed compilation because scalar @list

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl. I find out that code as follows cannot run:

```
#! perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    my @classes = qw(Animal Cow Sheep Horse Mouse);
    use Test::More tests => scalar @classes;
}
```

If I change `scalar @classes` to `5`, it is ok. If I change `use Test::More tests => scalar @classes;` to `print scalar @classes;`, it is ok. But when they are together, they are wrong.  Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this would be to use the `plan` function instead of specifying the number of tests in the `use` statement:

```
use Test::More;
my @classes = qw(Animal Cow Sheep Horse Mouse);
plan(tests => scalar @classes);
```

If you insist on specifying the number of tests in the `use`, you need either

```
my @classes;
BEGIN {
    @classes = qw(Animal Cow Sheep Horse Mouse);
}
use Test::More tests => scalar @classes;
```

or

```
BEGIN {
    my @classes = qw(Animal Cow Sheep Horse Mouse);
    require Test::More;
    Test::More->import(tests => scalar @classes);
}
```

The problem is that `use` is evaluated at compile-time.  You put it inside a `BEGIN` block, which is also evaluated at compile-time, but the `BEGIN` block has its own compilation phase.

Because the `use` is executed before the rest of the `BEGIN` block, what you wrote is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
    my @classes;
    require Test::More;
    Test::More->import(tests => scalar @classes);
    @classes = qw(Animal Cow Sheep Horse Mouse)
}
```

That's why it complains about you trying to plan 0 tests.

Comment: If you're curious (like I was) why the `use` runs *before* the rest of the BEGIN block, it's because the contents of BEGIN blocks are executed after they are *completely* compiled. The order is: compile `my @classes = ...`, compile `use Test::More`, execute `use Test::More` (since `use Test::More` is now completely compiled), execute `my @classes = ...`. You can see this with `perl -MO=Concise,BEGIN -e'...'`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, yes, that's what I meant by "the `BEGIN` block has its own compilation phase" and the final code block.  Also, `my` has both a compile-time and run-time effect.  The compile-time effect is why you don't get a "Global symbol `@classes` requires explicit package name" error, but the assignment doesn't happen until run-time.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `use MODULE` is exactly equivalent to `BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }` (see `perldoc -f use`).

I suspect the BEGIN within a a BEGIN block is causing the problem, and indeed, replacing the code with

```
#! perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    my @classes = qw(Animal Cow Sheep Horse Mouse);
    require Test::More; Test::More->import( tests => scalar @classes );
}
```

seems work fine.